# Disabling notifications from S Planner results in notifications that you have disabled notifications *facepalm

Tags: calendar, samsung-galaxy-note-4, s-planner

I have tried to disable my S Planner because I use an alternative calendar app. Now that I have turned off notifications I get the same notification constantly  (reappears almost instantly after cleared) informing me that I have disabled notifications.

Yes, a notification from the app to let me know I have disabled notifications. Face palm and wtf. Probably the most annoying thing I have ever encountered on Android.

The indestructible Message Reads:

"S Planner noti. not shown
To receive notifications from S Planner, tap SETTINGS, go to App info > Permissions, then allow the following permissions:
Calendar"

I have disabled everything all permissions, notifications, default settints, stopped the app, even restricted its use to wifi.

I have tried to do my due diligence and look for a post that answers this question but could not find it, if such a post exists kindly link to it.

Thanks